# Back to top link on longer pages with dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a slight problem with the way my pages work and the back to top link I am using.

The back to top link works well on static pages but if I reveal more content (dynamically making the page longer) it doesn't recalculate the height of the window. This must be a common problem - I suspect?

Here is the javascript for the back to top link generation:

```
// Affixes the "back to top" button
if ( (jQuery(window).height() + 200) < jQuery(document).height() ) {
jQuery('#top-link-block').removeClass('hidden').affix({
    // how far to scroll down before link "slides" into view
    offset: {
        top: 200
    }
});
```

}

Comment: This is not a common problem if you call `jQuery(document).height()` or `jQuery(window).height()` it will get the latest height, you are probably only checking this once. Can you post more code?

Comment: I would just stick an `anchor` somewhere in the top and link to it. With some `CSS` you can have an animation effect. No need of `JS` then.

Comment: You'll need to re-run this function as a callback on your dynamic load function to update values.

Comment: I have just realised that this method is a bit flawed. Instead I opted for some code that uses the scroll function rather than trying to determine the window/document height. Works much better:

http://www.developerdrive.com/2013/07/using-jquery-to-add-a-dynamic-back-to-top-floating-button-with-smooth-scroll/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just realised that this method is a bit flawed. Instead I opted for some code that uses the scroll function rather than trying to determine the window/document height. Works much better:

http://www.developerdrive.com/2013/07/using-jquery-to-add-a-dynamic-back-to-top-floating-button-with-smooth-scroll/